# Strange Knitr behavior with APA6 class manuscript

Tags: knitr, apa6

I tried everything that I know to solve this problem. I normally write my homework on share latex, but for this I downloaded and installed MacTex, Sweave and Knitr on my Mac. After trying out every tutorial and combination I could find I could not find the source of my problem.

When I use Knitr or Sweave, it sometimes gives the error:

```
Typesetting problem in main.tex: Underfull \vbox (badness 10000)
has occurred while \output is active []
```

The result is that certain section headings have around 4 to 5 newlines of white space extra. When I remove the use of \Sexpr and in other cases knitr code chunks, then the problem disappears.

This only happens with the manuscript version of the class. Furthermore, it only occurs when `echo = FALSE` with a chunk. It does not give  the error when I type half a page extra. But typing extra stuff is not how I want to resolve this problem.

How would I go about solving this, where would I need to look? I've looked for 3 hours myself, but I am a beginner in LaTeX.

**Edit**: I noticed there is also an apa6e class. The problem does not get produced there. It does report all kinds of hbox errors, but I do not see them in the layout.

**Edit2**: when I use the option `a4paper` then there are less underflows (`letter` is the default). At the moment I do not see any visual `\vbox` underflows. It might be a possible solution. But I am not sure yet, because this problem occurs 'dynamically'.

Here is a minimal reproducible example (if you do this at sharelatex.com be sure to rename the *.tex file to *.Rtex or *.Rnw on your local TeX editor with Knitr installed via R).

If you remove the last "bla" the problem does not occur. It has something to do with the output of Knitr and its `\sexpr`, the section heading "methode" and having a full page under one section.

```
\documentclass[man]{apa6}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{Statistiek 2 Verslag: agressie en haar gevolgen}
\shorttitle{agressie en haar gevolgen}

\author{Melvin}

\abstract{Dit is een abstract van mijn statistiek 2 verslag.}

\newcommand{\SES}{sociaal economische status}

\begin{document}

\maketitle %error gets not reproduced without make title

<<test, echo = FALSE, warning = FALSE, results = "hide">>=
options(scipen = 1, digits = 2)
aantal = 100
rf_meisjes = 55
rf_jongens = 55
ses_laag = 5
ses_midden = 2
ses_hoog = 2
@

\section{Inleiding}

Agressie heeft een mogelijke negatieve invloed op de persoon en de maatschappij. Zo suggereert onderzoek dat agressie op jonge leeftijd een positief verband heeft met politiecontact (ref) Een ander resultaat is dat oncontroleerbare niet geplande agressie een positief verband heeft met sociale verwerping (ref). De voorgaande onderzoeken impliceren dat agressie een voorspeller is van een eenzamere en meer criminele maatschappij. Daarom is onderzoek in dit onderwerp van maatschappelijk belang.

De literatuur gebruikt verschillende definities van agressie. Zonder een eenduidige definitie is het onmogelijk om heldere interpreteerbare resultaten te verwachten. In dit verslag wordt geprobeerd een eenduidige algemene definitie te hanteren. Agressie wordt in dit verslag gedefinieerd als: het (bewust of onbewust) gebruiken van sociaal-relationele wapens tegen een ander persoon. Deze definitie is ge\"inspireerd door (ref).

Bij de eerste hypothese werd er verwacht dat de mate van agressie een positief verband heeft met leeftijd bij een lage \SES, maar niet bij een gemiddelde \SES\ en een hoge \SES. Zie figuur .. op pagina .. voor een hypothetische grafische weergave. 
Bij de tweede hypothese werd er verwacht dat de mate van verwerping van leeftijdsgenoten en de snelheid van boos worden op zevenjarige leeftijd een positieve verband hebben op agressie met zevenjarige leeftijd. Bij de derde hypothese werd er verwacht dat de mate van agressie op zevenjarige leeftijd en een lage \SES\ een positieve verband hebben met politie contact blablablabla. %remove the last "bla" and the error does not occur

\section{Methode} 

\subsection{Participanten}
Er waren \Sexpr{aantal} participanten (waarvan \Sexpr{rf_meisjes}\% meisjes en \Sexpr{rf_jongens}\% jongens). Van deze groep hadden \Sexpr{ses_laag}\% kinderen een lage \SES, \Sexpr{ses_midden}\% kinderen een gemiddelde \SES en \Sexpr{ses_hoog}\% kinderen een hoge \SES. De participanten waren geworven via verschillende peuterspeelzalen in Noord-Holland.

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{referenties}
\end{document}
```

Comment: As always, as long as you do not provide a minimal working example, it is nearly impossible to help

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot. I will create one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a solid solution, but the best solution I currently came up with. Apparently by selecting the option `a4paper` and / or `noextraspace` the visual problems go away.

With the option of `noextraspace` it almost looks like the author of the class file has foreseen the problem.

> **noextraspace**: In man mode, removes some of the vertical space between certain elements (e.g., headers and text) in an attempt to more closely re- semble true double-spacing (use at your own risk).

For the full documentation see
http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/apa6/apa6.pdf

Comment: please get used to writing ctan addresses like: [http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/apa6/apa6.pdf](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/apa6/apa6.pdf) — that way, traffic is sent to somewhere physically near the person downloading, not somewhere near you (you wouldn’t want to overload `cs.uu.nl` would you?)